# three particles on a state with negative energy have negative temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Suppose three particles on a state with energy $-\epsilon$, that is, $H\lvert\Phi_1\rangle=-\epsilon\lvert\Phi_1\rangle$, as the average energy per particle is $kT$, but is also $-\epsilon/3$, wouldn't the temperature be negative?

Answer (score 0):

No. Negative temperature is related to [population inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion). That is, when a system is more likely to be found in states with higher energy than lower ones by more than the number of states would suggest. Think of it this way - at infinite temperature, all states are equally probable, regardless of energy. So the probability of observing a system to have a particular energy depends only on the number of states there are with that energy. At lower temperature, lower energy states are more probable than higher energy ones, relative to the number of states.

Population inversion is when the reverse is true - high energy states are more probable than they would be at infinite temperature. Mathematically, the temperature is then negative. Since such a system could transfer energy to a state at infinite temperature, it is actually *hotter* than a system at infinite temperature, in some sense.

This makes more sense if you think about inverse temperature, $\beta = \frac{1}{kT}$, where the hotter a system is the lower $\beta$ is. Then a system at absolute zero is at positive infinite $\beta$, and it is easy to see how a negative temperature system his hotter.

The statements about "average energy" being related to temperature are all, implicitly, statements about energy above the ground (lowest energy) state. That such a state exists is part of the [third law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics). Thus, in thermodynamics we always, implicitly, subtracting the ground state energy, and that's why we talk about "negative energy" not being possible.